# Integer Operations

Tags: secondary-education

I'm curious what strategies people have found effective for teaching operations with integers, specifically addition and subtraction. I've used number lines and zero pairs (drawings and two-colored counters). Is there a specific order that would be better when introducing multiple strategies?

Comment: You might check out: Karp et al. (2011). Developing Essential Understanding of Addition and Subtraction for Teaching Mathematics in Pre-K-Grade 2. National Council of Teachers of Mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

The age matters. I use money (including debt), temperature, and sometimes height (above or below ground) with my community college students. [James Tanton](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jamestanton.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2012%2F03%2FCurriculum-Newsletter_June-2013.pdf&ei=RcUJVIaGJYi6ogS9lIDYDg&usg=AFQjCNE2Zis30tndkZYZ7FwQvCM_oiqUig&sig2=2EmBComyrZex_fJaV-4HqQ&bvm=bv.74649129,d.cGU) has a metaphor with sand piles and holes in the sand.

Comment: As a total side-note: The presence of the word 'sandpile' in mathematics (e.g. http://mathoverflow.net/search?q=sandpile) is rather surprising (to me!).